# Mutate object with ramda.js path

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a structure, like this

```
   [{
      title: "Section 1",
      items: [{
          title: 'Dashboard',
          icon: 'tachometer-alt',
          route: '/dashboard',
          opened: false
        },
        {
          title: 'Appointments',
          icon: 'calendar-alt',
          route: '/appointments',
          opened: true
        },
        {
          title: 'Orders',
          icon: 'box',
          route: '/orders',
          opened: false,
          children: [{
            title: 'Orders submenu 1',
            route: '/orders/sub1',
            opened: false,
            children: [{
              title: 'Orders submenu 1 subsubmenu 1',
              route: '/orders/sub1/sub1sub1'
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }]
```

These are basically sections with menu items and every menu item could contain submenus, submenus have subsubmenus, etc.

I have a toggle function, which is getting a property array. I want to negate the  variable that is "marked" by this array, so when I am getting an `[0, 'items', 2, 'children', 0, 'opened']` array, the expected behaviour would be that the "Orders submenu 1" has its "opened" property set to "true".

The property indexer array is alterable too, so I can tweak that a little bit, if needed.

With Ramda, i can easly get the current value with `R.path([0, 'items', 1, 'opened'], menu)` but how can I set it to "true"?

Jsfiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/hurtonypeter/1tm4wcuo/

Comment: Note that while the answers with `lensPath` and `assocPath` create a new object for you with the correct properties, they do not mutate your original object.  This is central to Ramda; no Ramda functions mutate their input data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of lenses in Ramda to achieve this.

```
const togglePath = (path, obj) => R.over(R.lensPath(path), R.not, obj)
togglePath([0, 'items', 1, 'opened'], menu)
```

Comment: Scott's answer with lenses is better IMO, but just so you know there's also `assocPath` - `R.assocPath([0, 'items', 2, 'children', 0, 'opened'], true)`